# Trying to use python map to add input values to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using map to pass input parameters from STDIN to my function, dict_add,but when I print out my dictionary, it is empty.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Not doing this for any reason, just practicing python code.

```
store = {}

def dict_add(n):
   store[n] = store.get(n,0) + 1


results = map(dict_add,input("Number: ").split())



print(store) # comes out empty
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` is an iterator, so `dict_add` doesn't actually get called until you iterate it in some way. Example:

```
list(map(dict_add,input("Number: ").split()))
```

or

```
for _ in map(dict_add,input("Number: ").split()):
    pass
```

I'm not saying this is the best way to achieve what you're trying to do, but it's why you're seeing this behaviour.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. For OP.. Map should be used for transforming data into another format. If you are calling a void method you should just use a standard for loop `for n in input("Number: ").split(): dict_add(n)`. Further, using `store = defaultdict(int)` you could just do: `for n in input("Number: ").split(): store[n] += 1`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you use `map`, you can just pass in the value.

also `.split()` return an array and I think you want to pass the input as a value

also `result variable is never used`

```py
store = {}


def dict_add(n):
    global store
    store[n] = store.get(n, 0) + 1


dict_add(input("Number: "))
print(store)  # {'1': 1}
```

you can do something like this in a loop, so it return a larger dict

```py
store = {}


def dict_add(n):
    global store
    store[n] = store.get(n, 0) + 1


for count in range(5):
    dict_add(input("Number: "))

print(store)  # {'1': 2, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1}
```